# Book about how PostgreSQL works inside

Tags: postgresql

I would like to learn something more about **PostgreSQL** and **how it works inside**. I know basics like SQL queries etc., but I'd like to know more about algorithms and functionality inside PostgreSQL so I understand this ORDBMS.
For example I'd like to fully understand these slides: http://thebuild.com/presentations/uber-perconalive-2017.pdf

**I would like to have a book** (not a reference guide), possibly with examples and easy explanation for beginners. I can see a lot of books at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/books/ or in Google search, but I can't tell which is the one I want.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend this one:

> R. Ramakrishnan, J. Gehrke. Database Management Systems. McGRAW-Hill
>   International Editions, 3rd Edition, 2003, ISBN=0-07-246563-8
>   (chapters 8, 12, 16, 20)

Comment: Isn't it too old? I guess PostgreSQL changed a lot since then.

Comment: I used it recently. It fits what you looking for.